# JavaScript Quiz App Working Correctly But With An Uncaught Type Error

Tags: javascript

My code is working fine
but still I am getting an error "Quiz.html:179 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'answer' of undefined"

I don't know why
I have tried all the possible ways.
I am really interested in this.
Please Help Me!
`
let start = document.getElementById('start');
let buttonY = document.createElement('button');
buttonY.innerText = 'Yes';
buttonY.className = 'options';
let buttonN = document.createElement('button');
buttonN.innerText = 'No';
buttonN.className = 'options';
let response;
let score = 0;
let i = 0;
let displayQuestions = document.getElementById('question');
let questionAnswer = [
{
question: 'HTML is a programming language ?',
answer: 'No',
},
{
question: 'JavaScript is a Scripting Langauge ?',
answer: 'Yes',
},
];

```
  start.addEventListener('click', () => {
    next();
  });

  function next() {
    start.style.display = 'none';

    if (i < questionAnswer.length) {
      displayQuestions.style.display = 'block';
      displayQuestions.innerHTML = questionAnswer[i].question;

      displayQuestions.appendChild(buttonY);
      displayQuestions.appendChild(buttonN);

      buttonY.addEventListener('click', () => {
        response = buttonY.innerText;

        if (response == questionAnswer[i].answer) {
          score++;
          console.log(response);
        } else {
          alert('Wrong Answer');
        }
        response = '';
        i++;
        next();
      });
      buttonN.addEventListener('click', () => {
        response = buttonN.innerText;
        if (response == questionAnswer[i].answer) {
          score++;
          console.log(response);
        } else {
          alert('Wrong Answer');
        }
        response = '';
        i++;
        next();
      });
    } else {
      check();
    }
  }

  function check() {
    displayQuestions.innerText = `Score is ${score}`;
  }
</script>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you defined the button eventListener inside the next function. I made you a [little sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-murdock-h9km4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)